# Get the center of an element using jquery using .position().left()

Tags: jquery

Hello I am using a jQuery snippet that uses .position().left()

This finds the position of the left of the element.

Is there any way to find the center of the element?

I did some research and theres no such thing as .position().center()

so I would like to do something like this

`jQuery(this).position().center()` but this obviously doesnt work

Anyone have an idea on the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't the center be the left plus half the width?

Comment: sounds right, so .width() / 2?

Comment: potentially....

Comment: you can also use "jQuery.fn" object to create global function to this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {    
    return $(this).position().left() + $(this)[0].width/2;
}

jQuery(this).center(); // returns center of an element
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. i believe this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

$(this).position().left()+$(this)[0].width/2

you can just add the left position from the jquery function to half of the element's width. Just use the width property